# I cannot login to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after upgrade from 12.X

Tags: upgrade, login

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS. I am using HP Pavilion DV7 Notebook. I have also windows on my notebook. Windows is working after the upgrade. But when I login to Ubuntu with my username and password it goes back to login screen, and this keeps on every time i login. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found this buy searching Ask Ubuntu. I know how it is when you really need an answer. Try using the search features before posting next time.

[Same issue resolved in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?lq=1)

Comment: I have tried everything on that post, however, I am still experiencing the same problem. As soon as I enter my password into the login box on the login screen, it goes back again the same login screen, and this continues everytime.

Comment: I created another user, now I am able to login to new Ubuntu. When I try to login with my initial user, I am still having the same problem. Is there a way to solve this?